# How to avoid circular imports? (How to import modules)

Tags: python, import, properties, custom-properties

In Blender, as far as I know (please point me if I'm wrong), we can't make:

```
import some_file_in_our_folder
```

(With modules inside our addon folder). This forces us to import our modules via:

```
from . import some_file_in_our_folder
```

I learned that using the `from` method forces the module to load completely, triggering circular import errors when 2 modules import each other. (A thing that don't happen when we import using the first example).

BUT, there are lot of cases were I want to use classes and namespaces from other modules, because it makes coding and refactoring easier. Like, specifying the return type of a class:

```
def get_object_A()->MyClassA:
```

or when defining variables, to have autocomplete working better:

```
my_var:MyClassA = ...
```

For the last example (with the `my_var`, I know I could make the import inside the function/scope of the var. But for the method type declaration, it wouldn't work.

So, I was guessing if I was doing something wrong (maybe there is a way I can access the namespace of an already imported module so I avoid circular imports?) or if I just have to give up specifying types as I like.

Thank you so much for the help.